# Use Enter Keydown Event to move to the next Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I have a large form. As users are filling in values I would like for the **enter** key to take on the same behavior as the **tab** key (i.e. I want to move the user to the next `input` element when the **enter** key is pressed.

*Due to the way my HTML form is structured into various sections I cannot assume the next `input` is a sibling of the current input. Additionally, the classes and IDs of the inputs are not sequential.*

**jQuery:**

```
$("input").bind("keydown", function (event) {
    document.getElementById('keys').innerHTML = document.getElementById('keys').innerHTML + event.which + "&nbsp;";
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var e = $.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 9;
        $(this).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5a8kqshn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do your job

```
 $("input").not($(":button")).keypress(function (evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                iname = $(this).val();
                if (iname !== 'Submit') {
                    var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button, input, textarea, select');
                    var index = fields.index(this);
                    if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {
                        fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/5a8kqshn/2/)